# React Native Alert crash(error) Delete conformation

Tags: react-native, alert, onpress

I'm trying to set alert function before running delete function to confirm.

Here is my code.
Now this shows alert popup with title, explanation and two buttons as I expected.

However, after showing up alert, the machine stopped for about one minute.
I can not press anything.

After that, I can press both buttons, but nothing happens - neither console.log nor delete function.

How can I fix this? thanks

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Alert } from 'react-native';
import CircleButton from '../elements/CircleButton';


  handlePress() {
const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
const db = firebase.firestore();
db.collection(`users/${currentUser.uid}/friends`).doc(this.state.key).delete()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Deleted');
    this.props.navigation.goBack();
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
  }

...

    <CircleButton
      style={styles.funcButton}
      onPress={()=>{
        Alert.alert(
          'Are you sure to delete?',
          'never recover',
          [
            {text: 'Cancel', onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'), style: 'cancel'},
            {text: 'Delete', onPress: () => this.handlePress.bind(this), style: 'destructive'},
          ],
          { cancelable: false }
        )
      }}>
      {'\uf1f8'}
    </CircleButton>
```

Comment: `onPress: () => this.handlePress.bind(this)` should be either `onPress: () => this.handlePress()` or just `onPress: this.handlePress.bind(this)`

Comment: thank you for comment! but not worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
{text: 'Delete', onPress: () => this.handlePress.bind(this), style: 'destructive'},
```

to

```
{text: 'Delete', onPress: this.handlePress, style: 'destructive'},
```

Because

[arrow functions don’t bind `this`](https://medium.com/@_ericelliott/no-first-arrow-functions-dont-bind-this-d88da9e8182e).